# Architecture of i386 input file is incompatible with i386:x86-64

Tags: linux, ld, i386

I'm trying to create a simple kernel using Ubuntu. In the terminal I typed

```
ld -Ttext 0x1000 -o kernel.bin loader.o main.o Video.o
```

But I got the following error message in return:

```
ld: i386 architecture of input file `loader.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000001000
```

Comment: [same question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85978/building-a-32-bit-app-in-64-bit-ubuntu/85979#85979?newreg=9746c4d60a7740aa9d0d68f29667feb4) it would help you ,maybe!

Answer (score 89):

If want compile the file as 32 bits, you can use:

```
ld -m elf_i386 -s -o file file.o
```

Comment: This was the solution. When compiling/linking 32-bit apps on x86_64, setting emulation to `elf_i386` provides the correct elf format. So, for example, if you compile an assembler app with `nasm -f elf file.asm -o file.o`, the link command is `ld -m elf_i386 -o exename file.o`.

Comment: Just don't forget to replace `-o file.o file` with `-o file file.o`.

Comment: It would be great to set this as the solution if it works indeed.

Answer (score 53):

Use 64 bits instead of 32 for your loader and compile it with the following command:

```
nasm -f elf64 loader.asm -o loader.o
```

This should solve your error

Answer (score 7):

When compiling/linking 32-bit apps on x86_64, setting emulation to `elf_i386` provides the correct elf format. So, for example, if you compile an assembler app with `nasm -f elf file.asm -o file.o`, the link command is `ld -m elf_i386 -o exename file.o`
Courtesy: David

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same problem, i figured out that i am 32 bit registers(eax,ecx,edx,ebx,esp,ebp,esi,edi) insist of 64 bit registers (rax,rcx,rdx,rbx,rsp,rbp,rsi,rdi), in my 64 bit computer.
Then use these command to compile my program-

```
nasm -felf64 hello.asm
ld hello.o
./a.out
```

Comment: The 32 bit registers still exists in 64 bit mode, but you cannot just compile a 32 bit assembly programm to 64 bit without rewriting it. Porting to 64 bit can also make it necessary to adjust the size of data structures, as pointers become twice as large.

Comment: Exactly , you are right .But when we want to write code 0x86-64 (64 bit) assembly program, we have to use 64 bit registers.Basically faced the same problem and got the solution using  these instruction .Correct if am wrong

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, I faced following issue

ld: i386 architecture of input file `file.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output

**ld -m i386pe -s -o file.exe file.o** , worked for me