# Unable to compile a simple application

Tags: assembly, nasm

I'm trying to compile this for Linux Arch x64, I'm trying:

```
section .text
global _start
_start:
        mov edx, len
        mov ecx, msg
        mov ebx, 1
        mov eax, 4
        int 0x80

        mov eax, 1
        int 0x80

section .data
msg db 'hi123', 0xa
len equ $ - msg
```

And

```
$ nasm -f elf test1.asm
$ ld -s -o test1 test1.o
```

But an error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `test1.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use ld on 64-bit platform to generate 32-bit executable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30184929/use-ld-on-64-bit-platform-to-generate-32-bit-executable)

Comment: You are telling your linker to create a 64-bit binary, but your assembly code was assembled for 32-bit. Pass the `-m elf_i386` flag to your linker.

Comment: Duplicate here too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200333/architecture-of-i386-input-file-is-incompatible-with-i386x86-64

Answer (score 0):

When linking 32-bit apps on x86_64, setting emulation to elf_i386 provides the correct elf format. So, for example, if you compile an assembler app with nasm -f elf file.asm -o file.o, the link command is ld -m elf_i386 -o exename file.o.

So use this instead

```
nasm -f elf test1.asm
ld -m elf_i386 -o test1 test1.o
```